# Custom theme function for language switcher block

Tags: blocks, theming, i18n-l10n

I have a problem with theme hook suggestion for language switcher block.
I just need to place theme_links__locale_block() in MYMODULE.module file

**My module:**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme()
 */ 
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_links' => array(
        'variables' => array(
            'links'      => NULL,
            'attributes' => NULL,
            'heading'    => NULL
        )
    )                                    
  );
}

/**
 * It doesn't work...
 */
function theme_MYMODULE__locale_block(&$variables) {
    // custom function code ...
}
```

It works in my template.php file:

```
function MYTHEME_links__locale_block(&$variables) {
    // custom function code ...
}
```

I don't want to leave it in template.php because it is a part of my module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it answered here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7#comment-14989 ?

Comment: I don't see any answer for this question there. No idea what the node have to do with theme hook suggestion. I think the problem is with the hook __locale_block, but have no idea what exactly :(

Comment: Could you prepare [complete example](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

adding hook_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) was the answer.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter
 * 
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {

  $mod_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');

  if (isset($theme_registry['links'])){ 
    $theme_registry['links__locale_block']['theme path'] = $mod_path;
    $theme_registry['links__locale_block']['function'] = 'MYMODULE_links';
  }
}
```